# Transfer a Pipeline, or MapReduce, task to a different target after it started [python]

Tags: python, google-app-engine

During the execution of a MapReduce Reducer [python], or during the execution of a Pipeline task, I sometimes want to move it to a different module (i.e. target).

If I knew, before creating the task, that I'd like to run in on a given target I would write:

```
from mapreduce import mapreduce_pipeline

......
......

mr_pipeline = mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(.......)
mr_pipeline.target = "F2"
yield mr_pipeline
```

But I come to know about it only when the Reduce part starts. Only during the Reduce phase I realize how much memory it requires, and if it requires too much memory only then would I want to transfer it to a more powerful GAE module.

As far as I know neither deferred.defer(....) nor Pipeline would work here. An ugly solution would be to rerun the mapper using a new Pipeline task, wait for it to complete, and fetch the results from it. This solution is:
1. ugly and not very maintainable.
2. fragile.
3. takes unnecessary resources due to busy-waiting.

Is there any better solution? 
Should the Pipeline or the MapReduce code be modified to support this?

Answer (score 0):

You always can re-deploy your module with higher machine class.

Or, because mapreduce/pipeline uses task queue, you can update the queue `target` parameter in your queue.yaml:

```
- name: my-queue
  rate: 10/s
  target: you-more-powerful-module
```

Comment: I can't re-deploy the module since it will affect many other tasks that run on the module. 

Another issue, that MapReduce is run automatically as a response to user requests or as part of a cron-job. So I'll have to somehow re-deploy the module automatically: is that at all possible?

Comment: What about second solution? Why not to point your queue onto another module?

Comment: Will pointing the queue onto another module affect a running MapReduce task? Can this be done programmatically? 
If this works, then this will affect other MapReduce tasks that run in parallel, and has a complicated set of race-conditions when the tasks finishes and I try to downgrade the machine class of the queue back to normal

Comment: Your jobs should be idempotent thus its should be OK of you will kill them to move them on another instance class. Still, pointing the queue on another module will **not** kill any of your jobs. The new one will point on new target, the old one will complete on the old one.

Comment: The jobs are indempotent, but since some of them lack resources they will crash due to Out Of Memory (or I can simply throw an exception to kill them). The new jobs should run on a module with more resources.

But can this be done programmatically? I thought that it can be done only by deploying a new queue.yaml from my laptop, not from a GAE task.

Comment: From your question -- you have **running** pipeline, which how I understood throwing a lot of memory errors right now. Why do you want to update the queues programmatically? What is wrong with updating them once from your laptop?

Comment: Because this Pipeline is invoked programmatically. There are virtually hundreds of such tasks each day that have to run, only about 1% of them need more resources than the default setup. This can happen at night when I am asleep, and the system should react to that automatically and overcome the resource constraint. I can run all my tasks with more resources, but that will be a waste, and will cost us money.

Comment: Well, then you have to programmatically decide how much of the resources the pipeline will take, there's no easy way to autoscale it.

Comment: So what you are basically saying is that I have to either enhance Pipeline and/or MapReduce to support this feature or to give up and use much more resources than I need 99% of the time. I can't really know how much resources I will need, in advance, since it depends on the batch of documents I have at hand. 

Some document collections have an even distribution of words, but some collections have the same word repeating again and again. With these document collections the memory may run out when these words are being processed by the Reduce phase. I have no way to know this before Reduce.

Comment: In theory, you know when the task has failed (by `X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount` header) so you **could** mark create **another** task with different target (with same params) and mark current task as completed, if, for example, the task failed 5 times. Does it makes sense? Its not easy to do with mapreduce/pipeline, but you could just create a task for each job from mapreduce/pipeline and process it in your custom task where you will watch for failure numbers.

Comment: I already thought of it, and it is: (1) ugly; (2) difficult to maintain; (3) complicates data-passing, since it requires a new mechanism to pass data from the GCS which the Reducer reads, and pass it to the new task. This is  doable but my, and my coworkers',  work-hours spent on this will cost more than the inefficient resource utilization. I'd rather improve MapRecude and contribute it back to the community.